# Avoid jQuery (pre)loading images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string of HTML that I use as jQuery input document.

```
// the variable html contains the HTML code

jQuery( html ).find( 'p' ).each( function( index, element ) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Though, I keep getting errors that the images doesn't exist (in my variable `html`). The images in the HTML have relative URL's which doesn't correspond to images on my host, so naturally, they can't be found so I get 404 errors in my console.

**Is there a jQuery-way to avoid jQuery loading the images?** If not, I'll have to find all images and replace the src using non-jQuery which is a bit sad because that's exactly where jQuery comes in handy :p

---

Edit:

I'll explain step by step.

I have a variable, `html`, that contains some HTML code from another site. I put that variable in the jQuery constructor, because I want to perform actions on that HTML.

`jQuery( html );`

At this point I get 404 errors because the images in the HTML source are relative; they don't correspond to the images I have on my host.

- I can't use jQuery to remove the src tag, because I still get errors
- Writing a bit of javascript to modify the src value is plain silly; this is why I use jQuery

So, again, **all I'm asking is if there's a setting or whatever that avoids jQuery from loading the images in the supplied source.**

Thank you.

Comment: understand you. you need to replace SRCs from the document before creating new jquery object. ckeck code at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop images loading you need to modify html **before** creating `jQuery( html )` object. You can use jquery for that also.

```
var newhtml = html.replace('src=','nosrc=');
jQuery( newhtml ).find( 'p' ).each( function( index, element ) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: I guess there's no way to simply tell jQuery not to load the images huh?

Answer (score 0):

right after you get the html - replace the src to something else ()maybe to your own picture [global url]. ( simple string replace)

this will help you not to get the 404 - not found error in the console.

also you can make the html as jQuery - and set all the $("img") with your SRC or remove it if you want.

*tell me if thats what you after.*

### edit

what about

```
$("img").removeAttr("src");
```

### edit2

```
    string html = @"
<h1>
<img src="" ... >
</img>
<img></img>-bad
<img/>-bad
<img src="" ... />
</h1>";
            string result = Regex.Replace(html, @"<img\s[^>]*/>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. jQuery is loading the images it finds in the inputted source code, so I get 404 errors. I'm asking if there's a jQuery-way to prevent images being loaded by jQuery.

Comment: youll have to edit - as ive said  - the html . jquery cant just make a switch which stops img from loading thie src.

Comment: When I put the HTML code in the jQuery constructor, jQuery seems to verify all images. That's where I get the errors, so I can't use jQuery to remove the attribute because by that time the images are already being verified and returning a 404. If I have to edit the HTML, I have to use javascript which is silly because that's where jQuery is for. So again, I'm asking if there's a jQuery method or setting that prevents jQuery from loading images of the supplied HTML code.

Comment: ok so dont put it in the jquery constructor - treat it as its a string. see my edit 2