# How can I prevent loading from <img> via content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome Extension for GMail. When I open a sent mail, if an image is attached, it is downloaded from server. I want to prevent browser hitting **GET /url**.

I have tried -

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    $("img-selector").remove();
},true);
```

I have also used mutation observer. Both methods remove the <img> from DOM, but I can still see browser hitting that image url in Network panel.

So, how can I prevent browser hitting the url, and removing the img? It needs to be done in Content Script. You can assume JQuery library is available.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the URL patterns in advance, I suggest to use the [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) or [`chrome.declarativeWebRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest.html) APIs to block the image. This can be done from the background / event page.

([this first revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19425251/1) showed an example of the "beforeload" event. However this event [has been removed](http://crbug.com/333318) from Chrome 35, so I've deleted the example.)